# Linux utility to have two TCP server sockets talk to each other

Tags: linux, networking

I have two TCP servers and each expects a client connection, but I need to have them talk to each other. This is how the connection looks like:

```
DEVICE -> UART -> SER2NET -> XXX <- OFONO-PHONESIM
```

Ser2net listens on a port and ofono-phonesim listens on a port, but ultimately I want the device to speak to the modem simulator.

It would not be hard to implement the `XXX`, but perhaps there is something ready available? A suggestion of a simple suitable scripting language library would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/).

If I understood your problem correctly, then I can simulate your environment with three terminals.

In the first, I run `nc -l -p 1337`. In the second, I run `nc -l -p 1338`.

Now, in the third, I run

`socat "TCP4-CONNECT:127.0.0.1:1337" "TCP4-CONNECT:127.0.0.1:1338"`

and I am able to enter text in terminal 1 and it arrives in terminal 2.  And vice versa.